# touchesMoved:withEvent

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I got the coordinates of touchesBegan and touchesEnded.
But in touchesMoved can I get all the coordinates of the touch from touchesBegan to touchesEnded. 
I mean that when I put finger on screen and dragged to some position and then I lifted it.
So, can I get all the coordinates of the starting position to end position.
If possible, how I can I get them ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TouchesMoved gets called whenever there is movement on the touch. If you want an array of all points you'll need to add them to a mutable array every time touchesMoved is called.

```
- (void) touchesMoved: (NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint tappedPt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView: self];
    int     xPos = tappedPt.x;
    int     yPos = tappedPt.y;
    // do something with xPos and yPos like add them to an array
}
```

Comment: CGPoint tappedPt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];