# touchesMoved get all the coordinates swiping fast

Tags: iphone, ipad, coordinates, touchesmoved

I want to get all the coordinates in touchesMoved. The problem I am facing is when you swipe fast on my view than touchesMoved is missing few coordinates from the swipe.

I have referred this question too. [touchesMoved:withEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777940/touchesmovedwithevent)

Any solution for this ?

Comment: It's unlikely that you can get all the touch points. Can you tell us what you're trying to do so that we can help you.

Comment: @Deepak What I am trying to do is let say I am drawing one line and again I draw second line around that line which touches first line at any location. I want to get that crossing of line and according to that I want to have some action to be taken. I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to get missing coordinates.
Because calling interval of touchesMoved is not frequent enough to catch all fast movements. 
Maybe you can draw a path between coordinates you can catch.
That gives you a rough approximation of missing points.