# Get all points enclosing UITouch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitouch

I am drawing a line using `CGContext`. I have set my line width as **35**. Now when *touches begin* is called i am logging the touch point. But it gives only one point, I want all the points within the touch as my line width is **35**. How to get all points within a touch ?

Comment: can you help us by showing what code you have written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. You get that one magical point per touch, that's it. You best bet is to take it as the center of the touch.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this thread. I think it answers your question.

[touchesMoved:withEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777940/touchesmovedwithevent)